# When ever app does ajax request i want to add load mask

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my sencha application, When ever app does ajax request i want to add load mask and after request complete i need to remove load mask.

I tried below code but, its not working for me

```
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading..."});

   Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(){
        mask.show();
   });

   Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(){
        mask.hide();
   });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show load mask you can use:

```
Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask' });
```

And hide the load mask inside the success function of your Ajax request:

```
Ext.Viewport.unmask();
```

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy Try these

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method:'GET',
    contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType:'json',
    url:'http://..................Login',
    disableCaching: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    callbackKey: 'callback',

    params: {
        xyz:.......                                              
      },
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var res = response.responseText;    
        var jsonarr = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.log(jsonarr);
        var myres = jsonarr[0].Result;
        console.log(myres);
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);  //hide the mask  loaded ...
       Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype:'dom_flightlist'}); 
   }//end of success fn

}); //end of AJAX Request
```

After The Success Function Add the Load Mask..

Comment: Ok.. within success you making mask false, so when and where do you set the mask..

Comment: before ajax request u have to add these lines                                                       Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype: 'loadmask',
                            message: 'Checking Availability for this flight Please Wait... ',
                                  html:'<img src="resources/images/fl2.png">'});