# setMasked(false) not working

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

In my application i have used the Ext.Viewport.setMasked function, When i call the Processing mask showing properly.But not disabled when it reaches success.Here my code

```
    {
    Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
    xtype: 'loadmask',
    message: 'Processing...',
    indicator: true
    });
    var data = Ext.JSON.encode(obj);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: App.gvars.apiurl + 'AddItem', // url : this.getUrl(),
    method: "POST",
    params: data,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    success: function (response) {
        var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                 if(respObj[0].response=="Success"){
                 Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false); 
        Ext.Msg.alert("Success", "A new wish has been added To Ur Wish List");
                 viewgiftlist();
                 goitems();
                 }
                 else{
                 Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                 Ext.Msg.alert("Error",respObj[0].errorMsg);
                 }
         },
     failure: function (response)
        {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Error",response.responseText);
       }});
      }
```

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677860/when-ever-app-does-ajax-request-i-want-to-add-load-mask) question

Comment: i have tried Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask' }); Ext.Viewport.unmask(); but no use

Comment: what exactly happened ?

Comment: @Viswa the activity indicator is running but not stopping.. Its keep in running

Answer (score 0):

You didnt give setmask(false) in your failure message.. are you getting success response or failure?

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is in fact Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);

My guess is that your success conditional isn't working properly. This should be an easy fix for you if you're using console! Fire up Chrome, hit F12 and use your console. Use a console.log after you decode your response, then you can properly debug this.

```
var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
console.log(respObj);
```

Also, not sure why the success portion of your response would be an array, usually a response looks something like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"id":"1","first_name":"Test","last_name":"Test"}],"total":1}
```

Obviously you can craft them how you want, but just looks strange to me. With the above JSON the conditional would be like so:

```
if(respObj.success) {
```